# Docker pull скачивает не весь образ

Tags: docker, docker-compose

У меня есть docker-compose с 2 приложениями (1 написал я, 2 - postgres). Зависимости указаны, но если я делаю на другом пк Docker pull моего приложения, то postgres просто не скачивается. Скачивается только мое приложение, а без postgres она выдает ошибку, что не может подключиться к postgres. Как заставить ее скачать postgres? или может как то запушить мое приложение вместе с postgres, такое возможно? При запуске на своем пк docker-compose up все работает

```js
version: "3.0"

services:
  main:
    build:
      context: .
    image: laitkilla/my_sms_service
    container_name: main
    env_file:
      - .development.env
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 9229:9229
    command: npm run start:dev
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: always
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:15
    env_file:
      - .development.env
    environment:
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

`

Answer (score 0):

В итоге осознал, что на 2 пк также необходим docker-compose файл и env файлы для запуска. После этого все заработало